# How to install and import paperjs for Angular 2?

Tags: angular, paperjs

I tried installing paperjs by using the command

```
sudo npm install paper
```

in my angular app folder. Paper seems to appear in node_modules folder, however when I try to import it using

```
import { Paper } from '@paper'
```

it doesn't find paper module. How do I include the paper module in angular2?

Answer (score 4):

I did the following to get it working:

```
npm install paper --save
npm install @types/paper --save
```

In systemjs.comfig.js add a map for paper

```
map:
    ...

    'paper': 'npm:paper/dist/paper-core.js'
},
```

In the component

```
import { PaperScope, Path, Point } from 'paper';
```

Comment: Note for Ionic2 users: You can skip the systemjs.config.js part.

Comment: @mshamma please add the note to your answer

Comment: instead of map thingy, I've added this: `"node_modules/paper/dist/paper-full.js",` in the angular.json under build/scripts and then imported in the component as above.

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/985) thread there is no official typescript support yet. However, there is an unofficial typescript definition for paperJS [here](https://github.com/clark-stevenson/paper.d.ts)

Comment: I don't need typescript support. Just need to import paperjs