# How to use angular2 with paperjs?

Tags: angular, paperjs

I am new to angular 2 and I would like to understand how I should install the paperjs library in my angular2 client. Should I just type npm install paper? This doesn't seem to include paperjs in my app. Should I just include it using the `<script>` tag? Please help me understand how I should approach this problem.

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install and import paperjs for Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41388881/how-to-install-and-import-paperjs-for-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

this question was answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44319450/6786941)
I did the following to get it working:

```
npm install paper --save
npm install @types/paper --save
```

In systemjs.comfig.js add a map for paper

```
map:
    ...

    'paper': 'npm:paper/dist/paper-core.js'
},
```

In the component

```
import { PaperScope, Path, Point } from 'paper';
```

Note for Ionic2 users: You can skip the systemjs.config.js part.